# Unable to put JSON array of dictionaries into class object for my UITableView cell

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I have some `JSON` I'm iterating through (it contains an array of dictionaries) and add to an array of custom objects I made in order to work with the data and add fields to my `UITableView` cell.

I'm creating an array of my custom objects at the top of the page:

```
var warehouseItems: [Inventory] = [];
```

In my `viewDidLoad()` I have the following:

```
let urlString = "myUrl.php";
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!;

session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let responseData = data {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>;

                //print(json);

            if let inventoryDictionary = json["inventory"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                //print(inventoryDictionary);

                for anItem in inventoryDictionary {

                    if let id = anItem["id"] as? Int, let item = anItem["item"] as? String, let description = anItem["description"] as? String, let quantityOnHand = anItem["quantityOnHand"] as? Int, let supplierId = anItem["supplier_id"] as? Int, let supplierName = anItem["supplierName"] as? String {  

                        let item = Inventory(id: id, item: item, description: description, quantityOnHand: quantityOnHand, supplierId: supplierId, supplierName: supplierName);

                        self.warehouseItems.append(item);

                    }
                }
                print(self.warehouseItems); //This just prints 'Warehouse.Inventory' for every item I have
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not serialize");
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

For some reason it doesn't add the item to the `Inventory` object.  My tableView is blank.  It only works when I manually add a string to the cell, so I know my tableView is wired up properly.

When I `print(self.warehouseItems)` it just shows `Warehouse.Inventory` 6 times (current number of items my JSON is returning) in the output.  In fact if I `print(inventoryDictionary)` I get the following:

```
[["item": Item 1, "supplierName": Supplier 1, "quantityOnHand": 42, "id": 1, "supplier_id": 1, "description": Description], 
["item": Item 2, "supplierName": Supplier 1, "quantityOnHand": 1001, "id": 2, "supplier_id": 1, "description": Description], ... and so on
```

Here's my tableview protocol where I'm trying to assign the object's properties to my row:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return warehouseItems.count;  //Make sure to set count of array from json
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
    let row = indexPath.row;
    cell.textLabel!.text = warehouseItems[row].item;
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = warehouseItems[row].description;
    return cell;
}
```

In case you need it, here's my custom `Inventory` object class:

```
class Inventory {
    private var _id, _quantityOnHand: Int!;
    private var _item, _description: String!;
    private var _supplierId: Int?;
    private var _supplierName: String?;

    var id: Int {
        get {
            return _id;
        }
    }

    var item: String {
        get {
            return _item;
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        get {
            return _description;
        }
    }

    var quantityOnHand: Int {
        get {
           return _quantityOnHand;
        }
    }

    var supplierId: Int {
        get {
            return _supplierId!;
        }
    }

    var supplierName: String {
        get {
            return _supplierName!;
        }
    }

    init(id: Int, item: String, description: String, quantityOnHand: Int, supplierId: Int, supplierName: String) {
        _id = id;
        _item = item;
        _description = description;
        _quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand;
        _supplierId = supplierId;
        _supplierName = supplierName;

    }
```

My head is spinning since I switched to swift, especially all the optionals and unwrapping.

Comment: Just a note: In your `Inventory` class. Instead of using `private var _id: Int` and a computed property you can simply use `private(set) var id: Int` which has exactly the same behavior which you can apply to all properties.

Comment: That looks MUCH cleaner.  Thank you!

Comment: I've taken your code, and the print result of `inventoryDictionary` and it doesn't skip that part. So I would suggest you to print every assignment in the `if let`: `print(anItem["id"] as? Int)` and so on and see if any of them is nil.

Comment: Yea I considered that too. Turns out the fact that my mysql/json is returning strings instead of Ints. Once I fixed that it doesn't skip. But now it's having problems putting my values into my object array. I'll probably have to make a different question for that issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Since there are no answers and the title of the question would still apply you can also just edit your question for the new problem.

Comment: You need to reload the tableview or tell it that rows where inserted. You must do so from the main thread, so you'll have to wrap in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {})` block

Comment: Anywhere in my view controller?  I did it right after my `.resume()` line of my session block but still get the same thing.

Comment: Ahhhh! I did it after my `for anItem` loop and it worked!!  Thank you!  Add an answer with this and I'll accept it.  THANK YOU!